# How to configure Pgbouncer in Airflow

Tags: charts, airflow, kubernetes-secrets, pgbouncer

I have been configuring Airflow Helm using the official documentation found at the following link: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/helm-chart/stable/production-guide.html.

In my Airflow Helm configuration (values.yaml), I encountered a conflict between using `metadataSecretName` and integrating `pgbouncer`, and I'm not exactly sure why this is happening.

In the `values.yaml` file, I have configured the secret containing the PostgreSQL database connection information for Airflow using

```
# Airflow database (extern)
data:
  metadataSecretName: airflow-postgres-secret

# Disable the deployment of the PostgreSQL container included in the chart
postgresql:
  enabled: false
```

Further down in the same values.yaml file, I have also configured `PgBouncer` to be enabled and specified the secret containing `PgBouncer` connection information using

```
# PgBouncer configuration
pgbouncer:
  enabled: true
  configSecretName: airflow-pgbouncer-secret
```

The problem arises when `PgBouncer` is enabled with the above configuration. It seems that PgBouncer is unable to properly retrieve the connection information from the secret.

To overcome the conflict, I tried using `metadataConnection` directly to provide the connection details, like this:

```
metadataConnection:
  user: airflow
  pass: my-password
  protocol: postgresql
  host: pg-host
  port: 5432
  db: airflow
  sslmode: disable
```

This approach resolved the connection issues, but it has the downside of exposing the password directly in the values.yaml file, which is not secure and can lead to potential vulnerabilities.

I am seeking guidance on how to overcome the conflict between metadataSecretName and PgBouncer so that I can securely store the connection information without exposing the password in the values.yaml file.

Comment: Are you configuring your PGBouncer secret in this form: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/chart/templates/secrets/pgbouncer-config-secret.yaml#L38-L40 ?

It requires `pgbouncer.ini` and `users.txt`

Comment: Exactly my secret looks like this;

Comment: Also setting up airflow in the same manner and I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This should work in this case.

### define metadatabase secret connection like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic mydatabase --from-literal=connection=postgresql://METADATAUSER:METADATAPASSWORD@PGBOUNCERHOST:6543/airflow-metadata?sslmode=disable
```

pgbouncer host in my case = airflow-pgbouncer.NAMESPACE

do not use direct connection to the backed database, you should point to pgbouncer host here.

### PgBouncer configuration:

pgbouncer.ini:

```
[databases]
airflow-metadata = host=SERVER dbname=DBNAME port=5432 pool_size=10 
airflow-result-backend = host=SERVER dbname=DBNAME port=5432 pool_size=5 

[pgbouncer]
pool_mode = transaction
listen_port = 6543
listen_addr = *
auth_type = md5
auth_file = /etc/pgbouncer/users.txt
stats_users = postgres
ignore_startup_parameters = extra_float_digits
max_client_conn = 100
verbose = 0
log_disconnections = 0
log_connections = 0

server_tls_sslmode = disable
server_tls_ciphers = normal
```

By default stats user and password is "postgres" in Airflow. make sure to add it in users.txt too.

users.txt:

```
"METADATAUSER" "METADATAPASSWORD"
"postgres" "postgres"
```

create a pgbouncer-config secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  pgbouncer.ini: base64 of above pgbouncer.ini
  users.txt: base64 of above users.txt
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: pgbouncer-config
type: Opaque
```

### In values.yaml make following changes:

```
metadataSecretName: mydatabase
```

make sure to comment out metadataConnection section.

```
pgbouncer:
      enabled: true
      configSecretName: pgbouncer-config secret
```